# Missing datastore in ESXi 5.5 after IP change on disk enclosure (N.B. FC connection)

Tags: vmware-esxi, fibre-channel, datastore

I have the following setup.

1 HP DL380 G5
1 HP MSA2012fc drive enclosure with 2 FC controllers
The 2 are directly connected via fiberchannel, 1 connection to the b controller of the MSA (no switch)

I installed the HP ESXi 5.5 image on the DL380 G5.
It is configured with IP 192.168.0.100 I configured the B adapter of the MSA to have IP 192.168.0.101 via the serial management console.
I set up the LUN:s on the MSA and configured the data stores in vSphere Center and installed several virtual machines.
I can access both the G5 and the MSA from the browser to .100 and .101 respectively.

All OK!

Then I decided I might want to use th ILO on the G5 so I might need more IP addresses for it and wanted to move the storage array to .104
So I changed the ip on controller B of the MSA to DHCP and configured my DHCP server to give it .104
I was assuming that since th G5 and the MSA are connected via FC the IP change would NOT matter.

I was wrong! :-(

After I rebooted everything the ESXi would not see the datastores from the MSA. All my virtual machines are greyed out since they were set up on the missing datastores.
Even after a rescan.
I could still access both the G5 and the MSA from the browser to .100 and .104 respectively and the LUN:s were still there on the MSA.
I changed the DHCP to give it .101 again.
Datastores are still not back in vSphere Client.

So I have a few Q:s

1) If the 2 are connected via FC why would an IP change matter?
2) Why didn't everything show up after I switched the MSA back to .101
3) What can I do to get my datastores back in ESXi?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If the 2 are connected via FC why would an IP change matter?

There's no reason that would happen, as changing the SAN array management IP should have zero impact on the FC paths

> 2) Why didn't everything show up after I switched the MSA back to .101

I genuinely don't know, this is very unusual behaviour - does the MSA still think it's presenting the same LUNS to the same host/s? Do you have any spare space, no matter how small? if so you could create a new temporary LUN and try presenting it to the host - do a rescan and see if that shows up - I'm wondering if the problem might be with the host actually - what do you see in the 'storage adapters' tab on the host - can you see the LUNs being presented? Basically detail-us-up please.

> 3) What can I do to get my datastores back in ESXi?

As above, let's see more data and work from there.

Comment: One of the LUN:s is just storage for uploaded OS iso:s for installation. I guess I can delete it and recreate it. That will keep the other 2 LUN:s (for system and data disks in VM:s intact) I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: The firmware on the disk array was really old so I decided to update that.

Comment: and? any change?